# Activate multiple panels of accordion

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dynamic, accordion

I have a ASPX repeater creating an accordion. When the user hits the page I check the DB and see what parts apply to the user.  I want to pre-select one or more sections of the accordion based on a "hasAppied" field and have the others closed.`

```
 <div id="accordion">
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptAccordion" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>                             
    <div class="accordion"><h4><a href="#<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %>"><%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("HasApplied").ToString())) ? "<b>" : ""%><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %></b></a></h4><div>
     <asp:Repeater ID="rptGoals" runat="server"  DataSource='<%# Eval("References") %>'>
      <ItemTemplate>
       <div style="display:block;"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkAction" runat="server" Enabled='true' Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Description") %>' /></div>
      </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".accordion").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false, icons: { "header": "ui-icon-triangle-1-e", "activeHeader": "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"} });
</script>
```

` 
I tried addressing it as an ordinal. I tried applying an id to the div (Class = accordion) with the name field.  I also tried to add the name to the anchor tag and addressing it through the query string.  Nothing seems to work.  I might be missing a step.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I had to name the sections of the accordion, then create JQuery click events from the code behind to populate a literal.  This is ui side of the solution.

```
<div id="accordion" name="accordion"> 
     <asp:Repeater ID="rptAccordion" runat="server" OnItemCreated="rptAccordion_ItemCreated" >
         <ItemTemplate>
             <div class="accordion"><a id="section<%# i-1 %>" href="#"> Accordion header stuff </a><div>
             <div> panel stuff </div>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".accordion").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false, icons: { "header": "ui-icon-triangle-1-e", "activeHeader": "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"} });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        <asp:Literal ID="ltJsShowBlock" runat="server" />
    });    
</script>
```

Then in the code behind you increment i in the item created event.

```
public void rptAccordion_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   i++;
}
```

Then you create the cicks and assign the string to the literal.

```
private void preselectAccordion(List<sectiondata> sections)
    {
        var js = string.Empty;
        string format = @"$(""#section*"").click(); ";
        for (int i = 0; i < sections.Count; i++)
        {
            if (sections[i].meetsCondition == true)
            {
                js += format.Replace("*", i.ToString());
            }
        }

        ltJsShowBlock.Text = js;
    }
```